# how to stop Timer.periodic that started inside initState when leaving the page flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm running 2 timers in my `initState` function, here is the code:

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    readingSavedData();
    _timeString = _formatDateTime(DateTime.now());
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) => _getTime());
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 3), (Timer t) => gettingLocation());
    super.initState();
```

as this `_getTime()` functions are running `setState()` every 1 second on a Text widget that shows a timer.

The problem that it never stops when I leave the page using `Navigator` .. it keeps running and popping this error in the console :

```
Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose()
```

as it can't call `setSatate(){}` on a widget that is not visible anymore. how to avoid this.

Comment: by calling `cancel()` method inside `dispose()`?

Comment: @pskink cancel on timers or on the page itself,  if you can give me more info about it, I am a fresh flutter user.

Comment: i mean `cancel()` on your `Timer`s

Comment: check if widget is mounted. using if(mounted) setState(){}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on @pskink answer, i solved it using this method :

```dart
  Timer _clockTimer;
  Timer _locationTimer;
  @override
  void initState() {
    readingSavedData();
    _timeString = _formatDateTime(DateTime.now());
    _clockTimer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) => _getTime());
    _locationTimer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 3), (Timer t) => gettingLocation());
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _clockTimer.cancel();
    _locationTimer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```